# How to programmatically add Spin event to DevExpress

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, devexpress

How to programatically add `Spin` event to DevExpress WPF **SpinEdit** Control?

* Why can't DevExpress WPF works just like default WPF controls :(

**XAML:**

```
<dxb:BarEditItem x:Name="spinEdit">
     <dxb:BarEditItem.EditSettings>
      <dxe:SpinEditSettings />
     </dxb:BarEditItem.EditSettings>
</dxb:BarEditItem>
```

**C#:**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    barManager1.LayoutUpdated += new EventHandler(barManager1_LayoutUpdated);           
}

void barManager1_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (spindEditItemLink.Editor != null)
    {
        spindEditItemLink..???.. += new ????(spinEdit1_Spin);
        barManager1.LayoutUpdated -= new EventHandler(barManager1_LayoutUpdated);
    }
}

void spinEdit1_Spin(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Foo");
}
```

Comment: I notice that Dmitry also gave you a more complete [answer in our Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q352025.aspx). As to the question you posed in passing here, let me just say that in order to provide the features and flexibility we surface in our WPF controls (and that our customers need), we sometimes have to go beyond the simple API that the standard controls give you.

Cheers, Julian (CTO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach an event handler to the [SpinEdit.Spin](http://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpressXpfEditorsTextEdit_Spintopic.aspx) event via the editor style:

```
<dxb:BarEditItem x:Name="comboBox" Content="ComboBox" EditWidth="150">
    <dxb:BarEditItem.EditStyle>
        <Style TargetType="dxe:SpinEdit">
            <EventSetter Event="Spin" Handler="OnSpin"/>
        </Style>
    </dxb:BarEditItem.EditStyle>
    <dxb:BarEditItem.EditSettings>
        <dxe:SpinEditSettings/>
    </dxb:BarEditItem.EditSettings>
</dxb:BarEditItem>
```